# How to give permissions to other user after logging as root in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have one machine which is `machineA` and I have a `root` access to that machine.

Now I need to create these below two directories and give permissions to `app` user.

```
Create ZooKeeper Data directory and give permissions to app : /opt/zookeeper/data
Create ZooKeeper Log directory and give permissions to app : /opt/zookeeper/log
```

I have already created those directories in `/opt` folder by logging as `root` -

```
root@machineA:/opt# ls -lt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec 17 13:46 zookeeper

root@machineA:/opt/zookeeper# ls -lt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 17 13:46 log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 17 13:45 data
```

Now I am not sure how to give permissions to `app` user as mentioned above? I believe this is pretty easy question but I am not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `chown` to set user and group ownership of files and directories. For example:

```
chown -R app /opt/zookeeper
```

will recursively change ownership of that directory to user `app`.